# Repository pattern and viewmodels with counts in them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using the repo pattern for all my EF POCO entities. Consider, a product may below to manu entities. I have a view model that returns some summary information about each product, using the following ViewModel/Dto:

```
ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NumPendingOrders { get; set; }
}
```

So if get a set of Products from my repo:

```
var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get(filter: p => p.Name.StartsWith("S"));
var productDtos = ConvertToDto(products);
return Json(productDtos);
```

Where ConvertToDto is something like this:

```
return products.Select(p => new ProductDto
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Description = p.Description,
    NumPendingOrders = p.Orders.Count(o => o.Status == "Pending"),
});
```

The NumPendingOrders is going to fail because my repository ToLists() the result it returns. I could change the ConvertToDto() function to use another repo:

```
return products.Select(p => new ProductDto
{
    Name = p.Name,
    Description = p.Description,
    NumPendingOrders = _unitOfWork.Orders.Count(o => o.ProductId == p.Id && o.Status == "Pending"),
});
```

But if I am returning 1000 summaries, this method will result in 1000 queries to get the count.

How is this usually handled?

Comment: Repositories should return IQueryable so you can compose the queries.

Comment: A lot of repo examples recommend doing ToList() first, but I think I may take your advice.

Comment: The danger of iQueryable is that you lose control of when the query executes, and potentially problematic lazy loading behavior.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the repository interface should never leak that its implementation uses EF or others. So both IQueryable and exposing EF entities don't belong there.

You tell the repo **what** to do not **how** to do it. The repo will return a POCO suitable for tha application context (a business object for business layer or a view model for UI). Inside the repository though, you're dealing with EF and the best approach is to have a query specific for the use case.

Actually for this case, it's probably easier to have 2 (or more) queries with the results (you must ensure the queries are executed) put into ProductDTO. The point is this is not shown outside the repo and inside you can go wild with hand optimized queries if you need to.

Comment: So you would actually have the aware of the DTO's? "IEnumberable<Product> GetProducts()" and a "IEnumberable<ProductDto> GetProducts()" both off the repo?

Comment: That repo should return only ProductDto, because that's what the application needs. But the repo knows about Product as an EF entity and ProductDto as the result which will be returned

Comment: I likely have things not layered properly for this. As my data layer is nothing my my POCO's and context. By business layer contains the repo's. The repos return POCO's. My UI dll contains the models. I generally try to have the coupling uni-directional of all those things, so having the repo (business layer) return models meant bi-directional coupling between UI and Bus. layer.

Comment: EDIT: @MikeSW But if I creaed a dedicated DTO for each POCO in the business layer, then this coupling is back to one... If you google EF/UoW/Repo, most implementations have the repo return POCO's.

Comment: Business Layer should NOT contain repositories, only repository **interfaces**. Your UI should contain only view models  and should use services from business layer or a query repository from persistence. Repository implementation is ALWAYS in persistence layer.

Comment: I have struggled with this pattern for years, and never felt that I have got it 100% right. 1. If I have repo ifaces in bus layer, that means that I have bi-directional coupling between bus. and data. 2. In my summary example, if the repo is setting the 'count' fields in my DTO, then I feel like I am pushing bus. logic all the way into my Data layer. If I set the count fields in my bus. layer, then I take the performance hit of executing N queries rather than one. One way around this, is to have Data return IQueryable, but this often gets called a leaky abstraction.

Comment: You don't have any coupling because the business layer knows about an abstraction. Setting a count is not business logic. Further more, if you want to model a business flow, I doubt that counting rows is business related. And I get the feeling you need count for displaying, querying not for business use (modifying).

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it against a real database but just give you some ideas.

```
        var products = _unitOfWork.ProductRepository.Get(filter: p => p.Name.StartsWith("S"));
        var orders = _unitOfWork.OrderRepository.Get(filter: o => o.Status == "Status");

        var joinList = from product in products
            join order in orders on product.Id equals order.ProudctId into g
            from sub in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                Name = product.Name,
                Description = product.Description,
                Count = (sub == null ? 0 : 1)
            };

        var productDtoList = from j in joinList
            group j by new {j.Name, j.Description}
            into g
            select new ProductDto()
            {
                Name = g.Key.Name,
                Description = g.Key.Description,
                NumPendingOrders = g.Sum(p => p.Count)
            };
```